# Sprite is visibile through others

Tags: unity

I'm trying to give a card game the look as if you play at a table. The effect I'm aiming for looks like this

[image: Board Image]

The camera used is just a perspective angled camera.

[image: Camera]

The card is a mesh with a 0.02 thickness and has a sprite renderer at the back and front. The backimage is placed at 0.01 and the front image at -0.01, they work well and the card feels good enough. But if I add more elements on top, they are visibile through the back. The mesh is disabled to better see the 3 Sprites, the crystal is a different one from the first image (and not some weird perspective)

Front, side and back view:

[image: Front][image: Side] [image: Back]

They are layered like this

[image]

And all 3 Sprites are imported the same, have the same sprite renderer settings and Order in the layer.

[image]

The question is:

Why is the crystal visible from the back and how do I fix this?

Comment: Sprites are sorted by their center point, so if the center point of a sprite in the corner happens to be closer to the camera than the center point of the card backing, it will sort in front. You might want to use a Canvas for this - then you can control the layering through canvas hierarchy order, without stacking up z offsets.

Comment: If I use a world space canvas for it, won't I still have the same problem that elements lower in the hierachy are just going over the others? If I rotate the card, the element would now be displayed fully on top (so it either displays the front or back)

Comment: I found a solution thanks to the sorting order. Adding a sorting group to the CardFront and all was working as it should. Now the Crystals are taking the center point from the front card. Since the back and front are same size, there will never be a conflict as long as the camera is not in the middle of the card. Writing an answer if no further bugs are happening

Comment: Follow-up: did you encounter bugs with your solution, or is it suitable to post as an Answer you can mark Accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of the sub sprites was managed with an z offset, but certain rotations, placement or movements that happened closer to the side of the board were causing the issues. The comment from @DMGregory

> Sprites are sorted by their center point, so if the center point of a sprite in the corner happens to be closer to the camera than the center point of the card backing, it will sort in front. You might want to use a Canvas for this - then you can control the layering through canvas hierarchy order, without stacking up z offsets.

explained the issue. The solution I used was slightly different, there is a [Sorting Group](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/SortingGroup.html) component.

> A Sorting Group is not dependent on any other Renderers, and any Renderers that are attached to that GameObject and its descendants are rendered together.

I might have added them to each parent (the documentation stated one at the highest parent should be enough) in my Gameobject but left the `order in layer` always on the default 0 since the sorting was done already by the z offset. I can not remember why I added more than one on the GameObject right now but the result was working as it should.